# How can I prepare a docker container with all the required haskell packages and the required compiler preinstalled?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How can I prepare a docker container with all the required haskell packages and the required compiler preinstalled so that when I issue `stack build --docker` it starts the app build right away instead of downloading the dependencies and compiler?

I tried following the 'custom image' section of the Stacks documentation's docker section where it says

"Create a user and group named stack, and create a ~/.stack directory for it. Any build plans and caches from it will be copied from the image by Stack, meaning they don't need to be downloaded separately."

But this only seems to use build plans. It does not use the compiler or all the packages that have been made available in /home/stack/.stack path in the container.

How can this be done?

Comment: This repo may be of assistance: https://github.com/fpco/stack-docker-image-build

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I tried this on a small dummy project, and I was able to successfully create the image. But when I used the image to build, I get a bunch of linker errors. 

You can see them here http://lpaste.net/359106

How can I fix this?

Comment: Without more information on how the image was created, I can't be certain. Are you just using the `examples` directory?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I created the image by running  `docker build -t image-name .` in a folder that contained the dummy project folder, the stack.yaml and the Dockerfile (https://github.com/fpco/stack-docker-image-build/blob/master/example/Dockerfile).

After the image was created, I just used the image name in the project's stack.yaml's docker section.

The dummy project was created using stack new, and after that, the cabal file was edited to add a dependency (Opaleye).

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman And update. These linker errors seems to be caused by a permission issue. This command,

/usr/local/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db --global dump | grep opaleye

prints out the location of compiled opaleye library to be `library-dirs: /root/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-9.6/8.0.2/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.0.2/opaleye-0.5.4.0-BRLCqVY9AJXBFXQwXTO0hf`

This path is under the /root folder, which is not accessable to the `stack` user, which the build command seem to run as.

When I executed the build as root (after logging into the container), the build was successful.

Comment: Does it work to add an extra step to the Dockerfile to change file ownership (or perhaps even just `chmod`)?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I got it working by adding a step that make the `/root` world readable by doing `chmod -R +rx /root`. I was not able to get it work by changing ownership, but I have probably missed something.

Anyway, it seems like it works as I want. The build using the image does not download or build any of the dependencies.

The next thing I want to do is to remove the need to download the package index and build plans. Is there any way to add this into the build_image program? Or does it not make sense to do so to include them as part of the image (because it might change frequently)?

Comment: It might make sense, but I don't believe Stack will allow that to happen right now.

Comment: Also, would you consider sending a PR to include your changes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508207/how-to-pre-install-stack-dependencies-to-reduce-stack-build-time might be useful

Answer (score -2):

I haven't used docker with stack but ASAIU stack just pull an image from it's name. You need to build the image you need beforehand, as you would with any docker image then setup task to use it. For this, you'll need either to write a customer docker file , create an image manually or start with an existing lts image preloaded with stack package (I believe you can find them on dockerhub). This has nothing to do with stack but is standard docker use. If you are it familiar with docker I recommend you read the tutorial on docker websi.te.tete