# How to pre-install stack dependencies, to reduce stack build time?

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm building a docker image from a Haskell application, I'm executing `stack build` from within the container.

Because `stack build` is starting from a 'fresh/vanilla' docker image - all the libraries need to be installed/pulled.

---

Is there a way I can pre-install these library dependencies? For the end goal of reducing the docker image build time (`stack build`). I'd also like to be able to later on 'add' an additional dependency without having to once again `stack build` everything over from start.

**A possible solution:**

I tried a series of:

```
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" aeson
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" aeson-pretty
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" ansi-terminal
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" ansi-wl-pprint
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" appar
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" array
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" asn1-encoding
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" asn1-parse
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" asn1-types
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" async
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" attoparsec
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" authenticate-oauth
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" auto-update
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" base
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" base-compat
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" base-orphans
RUN stack install --only-dependencies --resolver="lts-14.27" base16-bytestring
```

However this has several limitations:

- dependencies are built sequentially (and hence slower)
- a side effect of also installing any executable related to this library. - resulting Docker image is **enormous - 67GB**:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                                                      TAG                                                   IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                                                          <none>                                                d2a95ef3622d        11 seconds ago      67GB
```

Comment: Here are some information: https://medium.com/permutive/optimized-docker-builds-for-haskell-76a9808eb10b Unfortunately, a full download/recompile is needed if you modify stack.yml, cabal file or any submodules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can manually install the dependencies in a single step with something like :

```
stack install --resolver lts-14.27 Cabal Only RSA SHA StateVar adjunctions aeson ...
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems to do it:

```
stack build --only-dependencies
```

Comment: Definitely did what I needed to Dockerize stack apps :D